# Git alias for combining multiple commands: git checkout and git status

Tags: git, git-config, git-alias

I find that every time I checkout a local branch, I do a git status. I want to add a git status to my alias for checkout to be more efficient.

I already have the following simple alias for checkout:

```
alias.co=checkout
```

I'd like to modify it so that no matter what arguments I provide to 'git co', it will always perform:

```
git co && git st
```

So for example, I could any of the following, and the alias should perform a git status afterwards:

```
git co -b newbranch
git co anotherbranch
git co -b andanother --track newbranch
git co -- "*.c"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To run multiple Git commands in an alias you'll need to modify your alias to use `!`, which runs a shell command, e.g.:

```
[alias]
    co = "!git checkout \"$@\" && git status"
```

The `$@` should propagate any arguments to `git co` through to `git checkout`.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably better off writing a bash script for something like this. Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $# == 0]]
then
    echo 'No branch name'
    exit 1
fi
git checkout "$*"
git status
```

Then whatever you save that file as will be the commands name, and then the first command would be the name of the branch.